# undefined al leer la variable de un input en reacstrap

Tags: bootstrap, reactjs, reactstrap

Estoy intentando acceder a la variable del `input` llamado name pero me arroja  `undefined`. ¿Cómo puedo acceder a los datos del `input` de reactstrap?

¿Alguna idea? Éste es mi código:

```
handleSubmit(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.name);
} 

<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <Input  ref={(input) => (this.name= input)} type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
  <Button color="info"  >Add</Button></td>
</form>
```

Comment: Estoy casi seguro que el problema es que el evento `handleSubmit` es lanzado por el formulario, pero quieres leer el valor de la variable name del `input` (y en ese punto `this` no es el `input` sino el `form` y por eso recibes `undefined`)... quería probarlo y ponerte una respuesta con una solución, pero no consigo hacer correr reacstrap correctamente. ¿Podrías crear un [mcve] o enlazar a un jsfiddle/codepen donde ver el código corriendo?